# python: get data from changing span class using lxml xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I want to extract 'Return On Assets' from wsj websites. However, my code is not robust enough to work in different conditions.
I able to extract data for ticker 'SCGM' using the code below but fail for'AASIA' as `<span class="marketDelta deltaType-negative">`

```
from lxml import html
import requests

StockData =['SCGM','AASIA']
page_wsj1 = requests.get('http://quotes.wsj.com/MY/'+StockData[x]+'/financials')
wsj1 = html.fromstring(page_wsj1.content)
wsj_fig = wsj1.xpath('//span[@class="marketDelta noChange"]/text()')
ROA = wsj_fig[25]
```

No issue for SCGM but for AASIA, it did not work as the span class is changed.
For SCGM, the html tags as below. Full link [here](http://quotes.wsj.com/MY/SCGM/financials)

```
<tr> <td> <span class="data_lbl">Return on Assets</span> <span class="data_data"> <span class="marketDelta noChange">18.26</span> </span> </td> </tr>
```

For AASIA, the html tags as below . Full link [here](http://quotes.wsj.com/MY/AASIA/financials/)

```
<tr> <td> <span class="data_lbl">Return on Assets</span> <span class="data_data"> <span class="marketDelta deltaType-negative">-1.36</span> </span> </td> </tr>
```

How to have a code that work for both conditions or point straight to 'Return on Assets'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//td[normalize-space(span) = "Return on Assets"]/span[@class = "data_data"]/span
```