# python: xpath lxml to extract data

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

```
<td> <span class="data_lbl updated-daily">P/E Ratio <small class="data_meta">(including extraordinary items)</small></span> <span class="data_data"> <span class="marketDelta deltaType-negative">-69.83</span> </span> </td>
```

How to extract data PE Ratio data '-69.83' in a robust way?
I want to point it straight to the P/E Ratio.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

StockData =['AASIA']
page_wsj1 = requests.get('http://quotes.wsj.com/MY/'+StockData[x]+'/financials')
wsj1 = html.fromstring(page_wsj1.content)
PE = wsj1.xpath('//td[contains(.,"P/E Ratio")]/text()')
```

but  the result is ['','','','','']

```
wsj1.xpath('//td[normalize-space(span) = "P/E Ratio"]/span[@class = "data_data"]/span/text()')
```

also result []

Comment: did you try to write something?

Comment: That is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488422/python-get-data-from-changing-span-class-using-lxml-xpath

Comment: You're missing a `span`.

Comment: wsj1.xpath('//td[normalize-space(span) = "P/E Ratio"]/span[@class = "data_data"]/span/text()') does not work too

Comment: Because the text of the `span` is not "P/E Ratio", but "P/E Ratio (including extraordinary items)". You need to either use `contains()` or `td[normalize-space(span/text()) = "P/E Ratio"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//td[normalize-space(span/text()) = "P/E Ratio"]/span[@class = "data_data"]/span
```

or

```
//td[contains(normalize-space(span), "P/E Ratio")]/span[@class = "data_data"]/span
```

Comment: thanks. It works! Can you add how to do it with contains()?